# Did European Muslim protestors carry signs "Shariah for the Netherlands", "Islam Will Dominate the World, Freedom Can Go to Hell"

Tags: law, islam, united-kingdom, europe, netherlands

Does the following alleged photograph represent an actual demonstration by real self-identified Muslims, in Europe?

[image]

I found at: http://www.billionbibles.org/sharia/sharia-europe.html

Comment: Doesn't follow you have to repeat their slogan all-caps. -- The article is ridiculous. Seriously. Not wanting to pick it apart word by word, you *really* don't notice something wrong in the picture allegedly showing "Venice, Italy" with people praying in a flooded street *with their heads under water*? I don't think that site is a noteable claim.

Comment: @DevSolar OK, I censored the all-caps out of the title.  I'm just asking if that one photo is an actual photo from a real protest by real Muslims. I'm not asking about anything else on the website.  That's just where I first saw the photograph.

Comment: @DevSolar does this make it more notable: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1220830/Far-right-Dutch-MP-Geert-Wilders-arrives-UK-winning-travel-ban-appeal.html ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The photo is real, it was group of about 20 people protesting the arrival of Dutch MP Geert Wilders in Britain in 2009 as described by [this article](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1220830/Far-right-Dutch-MP-Geert-Wilders-arrives-UK-winning-travel-ban-appeal.html)

That being said, I feel compelled to point out that this in itself doesn't substanciate the claims made in the article the OP posted, some of which have been debunked a number of times, including on this site.

Just mentioning that in case the OP is trying to evaluate the reliability of the article by examining the authenticity of the photos.

Comment: "*this in itself doesn't substanciate the claims made in the article*"...which are?

Comment: @LCIII I guess ventsyv means the OP article, but I was really just asking about the photo itself and linking the site where I first found it.

Comment: The Telegraph says "Around 40 Muslim demonstrators " and has a short video clip of the protest: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/politics/6347086/Controversial-politician-Geert-Wilders-met-with-protests.html